# Cannot properly passing the value of textbox in a table row from view to controller in MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send 3 values from a view to another action, using actionlink. I have a table . Each row has 3 columns , with id, name and bid money which is a textbox. The problem is the action link only passing the value of the textbox of the first row, suppose if I press the actionlink of the second row, it is passing, the name and id of the second row but the bid money which is in textbox, is passing of the first row.

my view code:

```
@model List<UdemyMVC.Models.Movies>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="danger">
            <th>
                Id
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Bid Money
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        @foreach (var movie in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @movie.Id
                </td>
                <td>
                    @movie.MovieName
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="bidMoney" name="bidMoney"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Test", new { Id =movie.Id, MovieName = movie.MovieName }, new { onclick = "this.href += '&biddingMoney=' + document.getElementById('bidMoney').value;", @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you are not adding the unique id to the td's so all td's will have same name and id similarly onclcik even you need to pass the id along with the name Charles has already given you the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add an index to the id of bidMony and use that index as a reference to the one you want. My razor is totally rusty right now

but declare an index

```
    @{ int i = 0}
    @foreach (var movie in Model)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @movie.Id
            </td>

            <td>
                @movie.MovieName

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="bidMoney@(i)" name="bidMoney" />

            </td>
            <td>

           @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Test", new { Id =movie.Id, MovieName = movie.MovieName }, new { onclick = string.Format("alert(document.getElementById('bidMoney{0}').value);",i), @class = "btn btn-primary" })



            </td>

        </tr>
      i++;
    }
```

I'm unable to test this but I think this is what you need to do. The problem is that you're getelementbyid see's a bunch of bidMoney elements but can only return one so it gives you the first one.